# Rails plugin containing a database migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

We're considering writing a Rails plugin that contains database migrations.  This is because the same tables will be used on multiple servers.  The plugin also helps us logically isolate that portion of the app.  Are there potential pitfalls doing this?  My only main concern is additional complexity.

I do realize it's bad practice for migrations to utilize models etc.